# Problems deleting entity mapped as many-to-one JPA (ObjectDeletedException)

Tags: hibernate, jpa, one-to-one, many-to-one

I came up with a solution to model a one-to-one relationship creating a many-to-one relation with a unique identifier (FK) to the parent entity.

Example:

```
<many-to-one name="parent" cascade="delete" column="parent_id" unique="true"/>
```

So, i have a parent-id (FK) inside my child entity. So far so good, if I remove the parent entity, the child is also deleted.

The problem is when I try to delete the child, I get the ObjectDeletedException.

Example:

```
child.delete() // throws Except.
```

I Already came up with a solution, if I set

```
child.setParent(null)
```

I'm able to delete my child without any problems, but I would like to understand the nature of this situation, is the way a mapped incorrectly? I know for a fact that hibernate sets the FK to null before trying to delete, but I don't know why in this case it's not able to do so.

Comment: you also have a cascade delete on the one-to-many relation , right ?

Comment: @osamayaccoub I dont have anything mapped on my Parent class, since its like a history/log class, I didnt want to "polute" the parent class even more because it has a lot of columns already

Comment: So it's a unidirectional relationship? .... From child to parent only?

Comment: Yes indeed.@osamayaccoub